# Query a joined data in eve-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy, eve

I am using -

- eve-sqlalchemy 0.5
- SQLalchemy 1.2.1
- PyMySQL 0.8.0

My domain definitions look something like below:

```py
class CommonColumns(Base):
    __abstract__ = True
    _created = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    _updated = Column(DateTime, default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())
    _etag = Column(String(40))


class Host(CommonColumns):
    __tablename__ = 'host'
    cpa_id = Column(String(30), primary_key=True)
    host = Column(String(45))
    port = Column(Integer)
    instance = Column(String(20))
    status = Column(String(10))
    partnerships = relationship("Partnership", back_populates='host')


class Partnership(CommonColumns):
    __tablename__ = 'partnership'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    cpa_id = Column(String(30), ForeignKey('host.cpa_id'))
    service = Column(String(40))
    action = Column(String(50))
    status = Column(String(10))
    host = relationship("Host", back_populates='partnerships')
```

After booting up eve and populating the data in the database. I am able to query for hosts and partnerships. They are also returning the host or partnership ids in the response.

Example response on one of the item belonging to resource partnership:

```
{
    "host": "0020",
    "id": 1,
    "service": "service1",
    "action": "action1",
    "status": "active",
    "_updated": "Tue, 30 Jan 2018 23:52:32 GMT",
    "_created": "Tue, 30 Jan 2018 23:52:32 GMT",
    "_etag": "e09fd6eb612f722ad26bf0b7f528f42d2f585d04",
    "_links": {
        "parent": {
            "title": "home",
            "href": "/"
        },
        "self": {
            "title": "Partnership",
            "href": "partnerships/1"
        },
        "collection": {
            "title": "partnerships",
            "href": "partnerships"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get it to include other fields from the host resource? This will require a join query in usual case but I wanted to know if it is handled in someway in eve.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `embedded` parameter: https://github.com/pyeve/eve-sqlalchemy/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst#embedded-resources

With `&embedded={"host":1}` it should include the whole host ressource.

I'm not sure if this works with your current environment / versions.